# Getting a timeout with Big Numbers

Tags: c#, loops, binary-search

I was solving CodeWars task(https://www.codewars.com/kata/5e4bb05b698ef0001e3344bc/train/csharp) and faced a problem. In it you are given the array of numbers, which length is multiply of 4, you need to visualise it as a (x1^2 + x2^2) * (x3^2 + x4^2) .... * (xn^2 + xn+1^2). Calculate the result of this and find 2 numbers, which squares in sum, gives the result of initial sequance. For example, you are given an array of ( 2, 1, 3, 4): (2^2 + 1^2) * (3^2 + 4^2) = 125; 2 numbers, which squares in sum will give 125, is 2 and 11 because 4 + 121 = 125; I wrote the code and it works with most of examples, but when i use big arrays such as (5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 6, 5, 7, 9, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8, 4, 9, 2, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 9, 2, 6, 3, 2) in result i receive a timeout. How can i avoid timeouts? If u can use simplified english cause i am from Russia. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ProdSeq
    {
        public static BigInteger[] solve(int[] arr)
        {
            bool simplified = false;
            var result = new BigInteger[2];
            var index = 0;
           

            BigInteger sequenceSum = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i+=2)
                sequenceSum *= arr[i] * arr[i] + arr[i + 1] * arr[i + 1];
            
             if (sequenceSum >= 1000000)
            {
                sequenceSum /= 10000;
                simplified = true;
            }

            var list = new List<BigInteger>();

            for (BigInteger i = 0; i <= (BigInteger)Math.Sqrt((double)sequenceSum + 1); i++)
                list.Add(BigInteger.Multiply(i, i));
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                var second = sequenceSum - list[i];
                  index = list.BinarySearch(second);
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    if (simplified)
                    {
                        result[0] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[i]) * 100);
                        result[1] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[index]) * 100);
                        break;
                    }
                    
                   
                        result[0] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[i]));
                        result[1] = (BigInteger)(Math.Sqrt((double)list[index]));
                    break;
                }
            }

            
            Console.WriteLine($"A: {result[0]} B: {result[1]}");
             return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Click the "give up" button in Codewars and have a look at the solutions there, if you can't solve it on your own. You don't want to get honor in Codewars for tasks that you didn't solve yourself, do you?

Comment: how to avoid a timeout?

Comment: you can avoid a timeout by implementing an efficient algorithm that solves it in the time constrain of the problem.

Comment: I understand that my code is too slow, but i can't undestand how to optimise it. Give me a hint pls

Comment: Whenever asking performance questions, please a) post how long a specific problem takes on your machine b) which machine it is c) the maximum time it may take.

Comment: What is the result of sequencesum(5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 6, 5, 7, 9, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8, 4, 9, 2, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 9, 2, 6, 3, 2)? Just I get an understanding of how large the number is. How many items are in `list` in this case?

Comment: you are building a list of 1190972610434660378 items and after you are searching inside it...you have to change your approach of the problem. you have high level of risk to have an exception of outmemory too

Comment: @Frenchy: 1.000.000 TB should fail with an OOM, not a timeout. Are you sure?

Comment: @ThomasWeller its too big number for my head...

Comment: https://wims.univ-cotedazur.fr/wims/wims.cgi?session=COC64FE890.3&+lang=fr&+module=tool%2Fnumber%2Ftwosquares.en

Answer (score 0):

To avoid to waste time to build the list of square number and/or to have an out of memory exception, you just test directly if the big number is the sum of 2 square number  like this : (its basic solution)

```
    //method which calulates the sqrt of bigInteger
    public static BigInteger Sqrt(BigInteger number)
    {
        BigInteger n = 0, p = 0;
        if (number == BigInteger.Zero)
        {
            return BigInteger.Zero;
        }
        var high = number >> 1;
        var low = BigInteger.Zero;

        while (high > low + 1)
        {
            n = (high + low) >> 1;
            p = n * n;
            if (number < p)
            {
                high = n;
            }
            else if (number > p)
            {
                low = n;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return number == p ? n : low;
    }

    public static BigInteger[] solve(int[] arr)
    {

        var result = new BigInteger[2];

        BigInteger sequenceSum = BigInteger.One;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i += 2)
            sequenceSum = BigInteger.Multiply(sequenceSum, BigInteger.Add(BigInteger.Multiply(arr[i], arr[i]), BigInteger.Multiply(arr[i + 1], arr[i + 1])));

        var range = BigInteger.Add(Sqrt(sequenceSum), BigInteger.One);
        var isq = BigInteger.Zero;
        var second = BigInteger.Zero;
        for (BigInteger first = 1; first <= range; first++)
        {
            isq = BigInteger.Multiply(first, first);
            var diff = BigInteger.Subtract(sequenceSum, isq);
            second = Sqrt(diff);
            if (BigInteger.Multiply(second, second) == diff)
            {
                result[0] = first;
                result[1] = second;
                break;
            }
        }  

        Console.WriteLine($"A: {result[0]} B: {result[1]}");
        return result;
    }

        var r = solve(new int[] { 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 9, 6, 5, 7, 9, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8, 4, 9, 2, 5, 5, 3, 9, 7, 9, 2, 6, 3, 2 }); 
        //one solution is 17123330522880 and 1190972610311564160 after 20 minutes
```

you could check quickly the solution by setting:

`for (BigInteger i = 17123330522870; i <= range; i++)`

to increase performance to trap the result:

1. check if number could be the sum of 2 square number (see differents algorythm on internet)
2. use parallel for loop to speed the solution (you cut the main for loop by 10 for loops for example)

but for this type of big number, the time to find solution is very long in c#  or ypu have to be lucky...
Matlab should speed up really the calculus...